# High Charts: commas thousand separator in pie chart. How do you do?

Tags: highcharts

I have a high chart and my data labels say Interest and balance when I click the segments of the pie chart it shows the value of 4 752.6 and I want it to show 4,752.60

[image]

```
{
      lang: {
        thousandsSep: ','
      },
      tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '<span>{point.y:,.1f}</span>'
      },
      chart: {
        type: 'pie'
      },
      title: {
        text: ''
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      plotOptions: {
        pie: {
          allowPointSelect: true,
          cursor: 'pointer',
          showInLegend: false,
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,

          }
        }
      },
      series: [
        {
          type: 'pie',
          name: 'Line 1',
          data: [
            { name: 'Balance', color: '#0000FF', y: balance, dataLabels: 'Balance' },
            { name: 'Interest', color: "#FF0000", y: interest }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `thousandsSep` property in `setOptions` method:

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
        thousandsSep: ','
    }
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vwpfe429/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/lang

Comment: Thank I will try that, once I get to my desk with the repo. I appreciate it kindly sir. If it works I will mark it as the answer...

Comment: I see your demo is what I need. So I accepted the answer thank you!!

Comment: I will also see if I can get the decimals to 2 digits

Comment: tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 2,
        valuePrefix: '$',
        valueSuffix: ' USD'
    },